# How to generate sequential sublist of a list with a skip

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sublist

I wanted to generate sublist of a list with skips. To clarify given a list for example `[1,3,6,2,4]`

I want to get all sublists like: `[1,3], [1,3,6], [1,3,4], [1,3,6,2], [1,3,2,4], [1,3,6,4], [1,6], [1,6,2], [1,6,4]...` and so on. So far I only now how to generate consequative sublists like `[1,3], [1,3,6],[1,3,6,2], [1,3,6,2,4]` but I am having hard time getting sublist with skip like [1,3,2,4] or [1,3,6,4]. Please help me out.

```
def sub_lists(list1):  
    sublist = [[]]   
    for i in range(len(list1) + 1):        
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list1) + 1):      
            sub = list1[i:j] 
            sublist.append(sub)   
    return sublist 

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
print(sub_lists(l1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
from itertools import combinations

x = [1,3,6,2,4]
y = []
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    y.extend(combinations(x, i+1))

print(y)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 3), (1, 6), (1, 2), (1, 4), (3, 6), (3, 2), (3, 4), (6, 2), (6, 4), 
 (2, 4), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 4), (1, 6, 2), (1, 6, 4), (1, 2, 4), 
 (3, 6, 2), (3, 6, 4), (3, 2, 4), (6, 2, 4), (1, 3, 6, 2), (1, 3, 6, 4), 
 (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 6, 2, 4), (3, 6, 2, 4), (1, 3, 6, 2, 4)]
```

**Edit**

To get first element to be the first use `sorted`

```
y = sorted(y, key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. What should I do if I always want the first element to be the first part of the sublist?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```
def skipList(lst):
    for i in lst:
        x = [i]
        for j in lst:
            if j == i:
                continue
            x.append(j)
            print(x)

a = [1,3,6,2,4]

skipList(a)
```

Comment: Appreciate the help. However, your answer generates [1, 3]
[1, 3, 6],[1, 3, 6, 2],[1, 3, 6, 2, 4],[3, 1],[3, 1, 6],[3, 1, 6, 2],[3, 1, 6, 2, 4],[6, 1],[6, 1, 3]
[6, 1, 3, 2],[6, 1, 3, 2, 4],[2, 1],[2, 1, 3],[2, 1, 3, 6],[2, 1, 3, 6, 4],[4, 1],[4, 1, 3],[4, 1, 3, 6],[4, 1, 3, 6, 2].  It has skipped sublists like[1,3,6,4] and [1,3,4] and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
d = [1,3,6,2,4]
def combos(v, c = []):
   yield c
   yield from ([] if not v else combos(v[1:], c+[v[0]]))
   yield from ([] if not v else combos(v[1:], c))

print(list(filter(None, combos(d))))
```

Output:

```
[[1], [1, 3], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 6, 2], [1, 3, 6, 2, 4], [1, 3, 6, 2], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 6, 4], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3], [1], [1, 6], [1, 6, 2], [1, 6, 2, 4], [1, 6, 2], [1, 6], [1, 6, 4], [1, 6], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2], [1], [1, 4], [1], [3], [3, 6], [3, 6, 2], [3, 6, 2, 4], [3, 6, 2], [3, 6], [3, 6, 4], [3, 6], [3], [3, 2], [3, 2, 4], [3, 2], [3], [3, 4], [3], [6], [6, 2], [6, 2, 4], [6, 2], [6], [6, 4], [6], [2], [2, 4], [2], [4]]
```